# Ubuntu 16.04. Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization

Tags: boot, 16.04, apparmor

I've been browsing through a lot of AppArmor questions and issues, but couldn't find a solution for this specific one.
What the user of question 689473 did to get the problem fixed in 15.10 apparently doesn't work for 16.04. Any suggestions?