# AppArmor systemd startup error

Tags: 16.04, systemd, apparmor

I've got this error while booting. aa-status says modules are loaded. Some in enforce mode.

```
Oct 07 22:44:29 pc apparmor[787]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
Oct 07 22:44:26 pc systemd[1]: Starting LSB: AppArmor initialization...
Oct 07 22:44:29 pc apparmor[787]: Multiple definitions for hat chromium in profile (null) exist,bailing out.
Oct 07 22:44:30 pc apparmor[787]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Oct 07 22:44:30 pc apparmor[787]: Multiple definitions for hat chromium in profile (null) exist,bailing out.
Oct 07 22:44:30 pc apparmor[787]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Oct 07 22:44:30 pc apparmor[787]:    ...fail!
Oct 07 22:44:30 pc systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=123
Oct 07 22:44:30 pc systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization.
Oct 07 22:44:30 pc systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 07 22:44:30 pc systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

There is a similar question, [Apparmor Init Failed, Exit Code 123](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767272/apparmor-init-failed-exit-code-123)'s answer is installing apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu, but it didn't fix it in my laptop.

I've tried to setup a chromium profile and I think I did, as it prevent chromium to read the battery level ond dbus. But I am not sure what this startup error is. I get the same error with systemctl start apparmor-service too.

I've deleted usr.bin.chromium-browser in /etc/apparmor.d/, purged and reinstalled apparmor-profiles and apparmor-profiles-extra

What could this error be? How can I fix it?

Edit: Same or similar question, unanswered [Ubuntu 16.04. Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794998/ubuntu-16-04-failed-to-start-lsb-apparmor-initialization?rq=1)

Edit2: I think this might be related to this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/apparmor/+bug/1503762

Edit3: debsums -ac gave me this about systemd and apparmor

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dnsmasq
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.chromium-browser
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.totem-previewers
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
/etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was painful. But I've solved it. Though I still don't know what caused it.

I've got another box that is running Ubuntu 16.04. It is not as customized as my laptop. I've checked its logs and found out that **apparmor.service** starts as it should on it.

- Tar'ed `/etc/apparmor.d/` of my desktop as root.
- Moved `/etc/apparmor.d/` to `/etc/apparmor.d.backup/` on my laptop.
- Untar'ed `/etc/apparmor.d/` in `/tmp` on my laptop.
- ran `rsync -avx /tmp/apparmor.d/ /etc/apparmor.d/` as root.
- `systemctl start apparmor`
- `systemctl status apparmor`

Answer (score 0):

You probably copied /etc/apparmod.d to ~backup, otherwise the rsync step would not work (or would not make any sense).